# Interested in tracking the events that get fired while user browses a site

Tags: javascript, events, browser, jquery

I was wondering if it's possible to do as follows:

In my site I am using a lot of jQuery plugins that fire different events that I don't know about.

Is there a way - a program, a browser add-on, or something else - that I can browse the site and get a list of the exact javascript events that were fired with every click?

For example, I have a jQuery plugin that when I right click on any element a custom contextMenu shows and then when I click on one of the options other things come up. I need to know exactly what Javascript basic events were fired:

```
 $('input:submit, button:submit').rightClick(function (e) {
    $(this).contextMenu('contextMenuInput', {
        'Capture This': {
            click: function (element) {   // element is the jquery obj clicked on when context menu launched
                doSomething();
            },
            klass: "kgo" // a custom css class for this menu item (usable for styling)
        },
        'Create List': {
            click: function (element) {
            },
            klass: "kfilter kdisabled"
        },
        'Collect Data': {
            click: function (element) {
            },
            klass: "kcapture kdisabled"
        }
    },
    { disable_native_context_menu: true }
);
});
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: There are thousands of events dispatched in a document every time the mouse moves such as focus, blur, click, hover, mousemove and so on events. If you mean you want to know which listeners are fired, likely you can modify the jQuery event management code to report listeners added using jQuery. But jQuery has no clue about listeners attached using other methods (e.g. inline or POJS).

Comment: @RobG or this -> http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

Comment: But why? If you are registering the listeners, then you already know where and what they are. If you are trying to discover listeners attached by someone else's code, then you know you can't reliably do that so what's the point of pretending you can?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to show events currently bound ....

here is an example of using this code : http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/CNjs3/

```
(function($) {
    $.eventReport = function(selector, root) {
        var s = [];
        $(selector || '*', root).andSelf().each(function() {
            var e = $.data(this, 'events');
            if(!e) return;
            s.push(this.tagName);
            if(this.id) s.push('#', this.id);
            if(this.className) s.push('.', this.className);
            for(var p in e) s.push('\n', p);
            s.push('\n\n');
        });
        return s.join('');
    }
    $.fn.eventReport = function(selector) {
        return $.eventReport(selector, this);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Use it like this ->

```
// all events
alert($.eventReport());

// just events on inputs
alert($.eventReport('input')); 

// just events assigned to this element
alert($.eventReport('#myelement')); 

// events assigned to inputs in this element
alert($.eventReport('input', '#myelement')); 
alert($('#myelement').eventReport('input')); // same result

// just events assigned to this element's children
alert($('#myelement').eventReport()); 
alert($.eventReport('*', '#myelement'); // same result
```

### Updated as per comments

If you want to see what is bound to these events this is an excellent tool -> http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, i need to call 'alert($.eventReport());' before my code? or after the user finishes to do the steps?

Comment: @Ovi have a look at the example i created - you can run the report after the page has been loaded and all of the events have been applied - add it to a button like in my example then click when the page has finished loading

Comment: Thanks!! but i now see that this is not what i need, this function gives me all the events that are applied, i need something to tell me what events fire when the user does rightClick on a input (for example) and then the contextMenu comes up, what events does the plugin se, and so on...

Comment: @Ovi The right is done using click and then seeing which mouse button was pressed - the report shows which events will fire on an element but doesnt report on listeners ... let me have a look if I can see all listeners ...

Comment: @Ovi this may well help you -> http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event but again right mouse click and left mouse click is a single event ...

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite what your looking for, but with firebug, you can log events for a given DOM element.

You can do this by right clicking on the element in the html tab and clicking log events:

[image: enabling log events for a dom element in firebug]

The event log:

[image: logged events]

You may also find the firebug extension "EventBug" useful:

- http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug
- http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/eventbug-alpha-released/